# vi: how to use a line as a command?

Tags: vi

```
cat a.txt
echo hi
echo hu
echo ha
```

**Q:** how can I execute ex.: the second line in a.txt when it is opened with vi?

so "vi a.txt" -> then SOMEMAGICCOMMAND -> then the "echo hu" is executed as a command. How?

Comment: Do you want the output to replace the command that was run? Where do you want to see the output when a command is executed?

Comment: Are you using vi or vim? I realize you said vi but I just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executes current line and captures the output in the file replacing the line

```
:. !sh
```

Executes lines 2 to 4 and captures the output in the file replacing those lines

```
:2,4 !sh
```

Executes the whole file and captures the output in the file replacing all lines

```
:% !sh
```

Same as above but without capturing the output in the file, just printing it

```
:.w !sh
:2,4w !sh
:%w !sh
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you're using vim**

I know that if you select the line containing the text (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) and then give the command:

```
:!sh
```

It will execute the selected line and replace it with the results.

#### Example

You can see what happens in the demo below.

[image: demo page]

Comment: `Shift` + `V` is not a standard `vi` command.  Presumably it is a `vim`-ism

Comment: @kurtm - correct, it's vim. I assumed he was using vim. Added a note on my answer.

Comment: how did you create this gif??